# Как проиграть звук в Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#

В Windows Forms в готовой форме при нажатии на кнопку чтобы проигрывался звуковой файл - как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [WMPLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)

в хэндлере клика:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
player.URL = путь_к_файлу;
player.controls.play();
```